# Function signature and inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, method-signature

Assume I have two classes `A` and `B` and `B` derives `A`.

Class A:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual const unsigned char* getArray()
    {
        return array;
    }

protected:
    unsigned char array[250];
};
```

Class B:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual unsigned char* getArray()
    {
        return array;
    }
};
```

Can I create a class C that will do this?

```
class C
{
public:
    const unsigned char* getArrayMiddle(A &a)
    {
        return (a.getArray() + 125);
    }

    unsigned char* getArrayMiddle(B &b)
    {
        return (b.getArray() + 125);
    }
};
```

With this simple example, I am trying to know if I can create two methods in the class `C`, one of them returning a const pointer if required by the type of the object it receives.

Will the compiler automatically call the right method in `C` depending on the type of the parameter, even if `B`derives `A`?

To clarify, if I have

```
A* obj = new B();
C c;
c.getArrayMiddle(*obj);
```

which function will be called? Could it create unexpected situations?

Comment: You could very easily put that code into a compiler and check. But it's quite bad to have the same method overridden without it being virtual and also changing constness.

Comment: I indeed checked before and it compiled. I'm also asking the question to ensure that this kind of thing does not require extra precaution to be used or could not get me in troubles in some situations.

Comment: They have different signatures so that won't be a problem. Still I wouldn't recommend having same public method names on deriving class without overriding.

Comment: They have different signatures, of course, but I'm confused by the fact that the method with the "A" parameter could also be called with a B object as B derives A.

Comment: "Will the compiler automatically call the right method in C depending on the type of the parameter, even if B derives A?" - what do you think is the right method? When you say "type of the parameter" do you mean static or run-time type (and do you, indeed, understand the difference between these types?)

Comment: I mean static type. If I use a pointer of type A* pointing to a B object, I expect the first (const) method to be called.

Comment: You can't define class `A` and `B` like this. clang accepts it but that's a [bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17859).

Comment: Did you mean A::getArray to be declared as a const function?  That would make it legal. Why are these functions virtual - neither one is ever overriden, so you always chose from one possible candidate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the compiler automatically call the right method in `C` depending on the type of the parameter, even if `B` derives `A`?

The compiler will interpret a method call as being to either of the two methods depending on the *static* (compile-time) type of argument expression. Whether you consider this to be the *right* method is determined, I suppose, by which one you want to be called.

If the static type of the argument is `B &` then the second variant (returning `unsigned char *`) will be called. If it is not a `B &` but is an `A &` then the first variant (returning `const unsigned char *`) will be called.

The precise rules determining which overloaded method is called in which circumstances are quite complex, but in general, a *more specific* suitable candidate is usually preferred. In this case `B &` is more specific than `A &`, so it will be called if indeed the argument is a `B &`, even though it is in that case trivially convertible to an `A &` due to the inheritance hierarchy.

**However**, it is worth noting that (as per comment from cpplearner) your code as posted should not compile. `B` should not be able to override `getArray` with a version which drops the `const` qualifier. G++ 5.4 diagnoses this as an error. You could instead not have one method override the other: drop the `virtual` specifier, or give them different names, or mark the function in `A` as a `const` function (so the function in `B` doesn't actually override it).

Comment: Ok thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to know and what I'm expecting.

Comment: I disagree. While technically correct, this ignores the possibility of unexpected results when somewhere inside C it calls a virtual function. But only if there are choices to be made in the vtable, which is not the case in the original question, so ... I guess you did answer the original question as asked.

Comment: @KennyOstrom not sure what you mean. It *does* call a virtual method from inside `C` - that's `getArray`. If you call a virtual method you should expect that it may be overridden and that the most-derived variant will be called. If you expected anything different, that would have to be due to a misunderstanding of the rules of the language.